# ts-node-env inside container restarting but not compiling files

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, nodemon, ts-node

I'm running an express app inside a docker using typescript.
I was using nodemon but as it take a huge time to restart I'm moving to ts-node-env.
I succeed to make it restart when there is a file change, but I just see that the compiled JS file doesn't have the modifications.

Here is my nodemon

```
nodemon -L -e ts --exec \"tsc -p ./tsconfig.json && node ./dist/app.js || exit 1 \"
```

Here is my ts-node-dev script

```
 ts-node-dev --poll --respawn --watch src -- src/app.ts
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: You shouldn't need an isolation layer like Docker and the complexities it brings just to build a Typescript-based application.  I'd install Node on your host, if it's not there already, and then tools like `nodemon` will work just fine without fussing with the synchronization layer or the differences between your host and container environments.

Comment: I need docker as there are a redis, database and as we work as team we need to have this harmonized env